# Maintain server after socket killing

Tags: java

So I have this simple server. What I want to do is keep the server running and waiting for another client, when I kill the clients socket (telnet -> end process).

```
private ServerSocket serv;

public Server() throws IOException {

    try {
        serv = new ServerSocket(port);
        serv.setReuseAddress(true);

        while(true) {
            Socket sock = serv.accept();

            try {
                BufferedReader netIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
                PrintWriter netOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream())), true);

                while(true) {

                    //do stuff
                }
            } finally {
                sock.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        recreateSocket();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void recreateSocket() {

    try {
        ServerSocket socket = ServerSocketFactory.getDefault().createServerSocket(port);
        serv = socket;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Atm it throws bindException, how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Add catch statement(s) to before the finally block (but don't call `recreateSocket()` there )

Update to clarify, something like this:

```
    while(true) {
        //do stuff
    }
} catch (SocketException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
      sock.close();
```

Comment: When I try to connect after killing the socket I get:
Could not open conneciton to the host, on port 8888: Connection failed

Comment: Updated the answer to clarify. If the client ends the connection forcefully (like closing it) it will generate an exception in your server and you are not catching it in your inner loop but outside it, killing the `ServerSocket`. So that's why I suggest adding some catch statements to your inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

Start a new thread to handle each accepted connection.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are creating a server socket again. You don't need to do this (the previous one is still working which is why you get a bind exception). This is what you want to do:

```
  private ServerSocket serv;

  public Server(int port) throws IOException
  {

    try {
      serv = new ServerSocket(port);
      serv.setReuseAddress(true);

      while(true) {
        Socket sock = serv.accept();

        try {
          BufferedReader netIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
          PrintWriter netOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream())), true);

          // do stuff
        } catch(SocketException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
          sock.close();
        }
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```